# How to make a data frame of a list containing vectors and a matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, vector

I am struggling with transformation of a list to a data frame in R. I would like to make a data frame from a list containing two vectors and a matrix (x, y and z). The data looks like this:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
z <- matrix(as.numeric(sample(100:200, 25)), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE)

lst <- list(x,y,z)
```

I would like to convert this to a data frame that looks like this:

```
x1 y1 z
x1 y2 z
x1 y3 z
x1 y4 z
x1 y5 z
x2 y1 z
etc...
```

With the column names x, y and z, respectively. There are a lot of questions already on Stackoverflow about conversion of a list to data frame, however I could not find an option for a list containing vectors as well as a data frame. The options I have tried so far did not succeed.

I tried:

```
#Option 1:
as.data.frame(lst)

#Option 2:
enframe(lst) #from the tidyverse package

#Option 3:
melt(lst) #from the reshape2 package
```

What did I miss and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(0,1,2,3,4)

set.seed(123)
z <- matrix(as.numeric(sample(100:200, 25)), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE)

df <- data.frame( z = as.vector( z ) )
df$x <- rep( x, each = nrow( df ) / length( x ) )
df$y <- rep( y, times = nrow( df ) / length( y ) )

head(df, 10)

#      z x y
# 1  129 1 0
# 2  104 1 1
# 3  187 1 2
# 4  177 1 3
# 5  172 1 4
# 6  178 2 0
# 7  150 2 1
# 8  198 2 2
# 9  120 2 3
# 10 155 2 4
```

Comment: `data.frame(x=rep(x, each=length(y)), y=y, z=as.vector(z))`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `expand.grid(x, y)` - which returns a dataframe - to which we add `z` after we converted it to a vector.

```
setNames(`[<-`(expand.grid(y, x), "z", value = c(z)), c("y", "x", "z"))
#   y x   z
#1  0 1 129
#2  1 1 104
#3  2 1 187
#4  3 1 177
#5  4 1 172
#6  0 2 178
# ...
```